# Is there a limit to how many columns a table should have?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table lets call it `CAR` and I need users to tick a number of check boxes between 10 - 40, to say if the car has feature a,b,c etc...

My question is along with the default `CAR` `columns id`, `name`, etc. with these extra 30 columns is that to many? Is there a limit a table column should not exceed maximum?

Comment: the question is incomplete..please provide details regarding the working.

Comment: Use another one table for car parameters, like `car_id | param_id | value` instead of many columns.

Comment: If you need to ask this question, you probably need to look into [**database normalization**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 1):

Maximum we can have 4096 columns per table, but exact limit depends on several factors. 
You can see detail blog here :http://goo.gl/Uh5Hf1

Apart from maximum column limit in mysql, it is not recommended to create that many columns in your table. Instead you can create a separate table which will store check box values.
As you mention users may (or may not) tick check boxes between 10 - 40. So creating column for each user is not required, instead you can create a table which store check box values with user id as foreign key, a sample table structure is as below:

```
id   user_id   chk_box_name   chk_box_value
```

You can store only those values which is selected by user.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

We can have at max **4096** column in a table in MYSQL.

From the [MYSQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/column-count-limit.html):

> There is a hard limit of 4096 columns per table, but the effective
>   maximum may be less for a given table.

Also I would recommened you to create two tables. One in which you store the information of the car like id,carname,cartype... and the second table contains the feature information like id,car_id,feature1,feature2...

Comment: Er, no. That's not how normalisation works.

Comment: @Strawberry:- I never said anything about the normalisation. And I am aware that it does not work like the way I said. As OP has not pointed any details thats why, I will update if OP comments or edits the question with details

Comment: You recommend the creation of a second table with enumerated columns. In a relational database environment, this contravenes 3NF, and is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL DataBase

Every table has a maximum row size of 65,535 bytes. This maximum applies to all storage engines, but a given engine might have additional constraints that result in a lower effective maximum row size. The maximum row size constrains the number of columns because the total width of all columns cannot exceed this size. For example, utf8 characters require up to three bytes per character, so for a CHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 column, the server must allocate 255 × 3 = 765 bytes per value. Consequently, a table cannot contain more than 65,535 / 765 = 85 such columns.
Source: [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/column-count-limit.html)